# How do I permanently set the referrer in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, security

I know I can disable `Network.http.sendRefererHeader` to 0 in `about:config`, and using the [RefControl extension](http://www.stardrifter.org/refcontrol/) I can set it on a per-site basis (or using wildcards, e.g. `*.com`, `*.org`). Is there a way to set this to a certain website, e.g. `http://www.example.com`, **globally**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) Firefox extension. In the extension's Preferences dialog, click Select Action and click Add.

[image]

Enter Add as the action, type `Referer` in the **Header name** field (it should autocomplete), and enter `http://www.example.com` in the **Header value** field. Click Save, and the rule should show up with a green light next to it, indicating that it's taken effect.

[image]

Note that some webpages may not work properly because they expect the referrer to be a certain value. To test this out, visit [whatismyreferer.com](http://www.whatismyreferer.com/).